# Boost libraries ! :(

Tags: centos5, cluster, libboost

I am in the process of running some tests on a cluster which has CENTOS 5 x86_64 kernel 2.6.18. I need to install a software there which needs boost>=1.42. I have looked around but cant seem to find the solution. I tried installing via YUM but it only lists boost.x86_64.
Can anyone please help me in this? 
thanks.

Comment: is it Rocks Cluster ??? Rocks doesn't include the default repository of CentOS by default.. Just refer to Massimo's answer below...

Answer (score 3):

What's your problem exactly? The package is there, waiting to be installed. Just do a `yum install boost`.

---

### Edit:

If the version number is your problem, then you can try looking around for another repository which has a more recent package version, or just download the source and use that.

See this question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559251/how-to-update-boost-when-yum-has-the-outdated-version.

Comment: I mentioned  boost>=1.42 . Current repositories have boost1.33.

Comment: Then please mention it in your question, otherwise it's not clear what you are trying to solve.